# Does SQL Server keep track of queries executed

Tags: sql-server, transactions

Can we fetch all sql server queries executed for a particular past time period. For example can we fetch all queries executed on SQL server in Past 5 hours. 
Is there any option available in SQL server for the same?
Or any other alternative solution if possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should work, as long as the cache hasn't been cleared:

```
SELECT      sql_text.text
,           st.last_execution_time
,           DB_NAME(qp.dbid) AS databasename
FROM        sys.dm_exec_query_stats st
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(st.sql_handle) AS sql_text
INNER JOIN  sys.dm_exec_cached_plans cp
        ON cp.plan_handle = st.plan_handle
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(cp.plan_handle) AS qp
WHERE       st.last_execution_time >= DATEADD(hour, -5, GETDATE())
ORDER BY    st.last_execution_time DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an Extended Events Session to collect this information.

[Getting Started with Extended Events in SQL Server 2012](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/getting-started-with-extended-events-in-sql-server-2012/)

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server by default does not track/record queries, mainly because this would make extra overhead.

So tracking of queries to be turned on via:

1. SQL Profiler (All version). Can hit performance of the server very much, especially if trace running in a Profiler app, but not started as a "server side trace".
2. Extended events (SQL Server 2008R2+). More lightweight alternative to Profiler and more advanced.
3. Query Store (SQL Server 2016+). Quite lightweight option, that comes out of the box. Can be helpful for performance tuning, but less for auditing.

All approaches require some understanding of pros-cons and initial configuration